# battery levels are not update its display always 100 percentage

Tags: android

it display 100 percent battery on app in following code please help to solve this

```
int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
            int l = (level*100)/scale;
        Toast.makeText(context,""+l,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(l==100)
            {
                Globalveriable.level = l;
                Intent i = new Intent(context, Charged.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
            else if(l<100)
            {
                Globalveriable.level = l;
                Intent i = new Intent(context, Battery_screen.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
```

Comment: please do some debugging ... I bet that both `level` and `scale` are equal to default `-1` used with int `getIntExtra` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
  int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
```

Toast.makeText(context,"Remaining Battery: "+level+ "%",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();